# extract product code using regular expression in Python and apply to a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pd.DataFrame` with multiple columns and one column has url extracted from web e.g.:

```
url = "http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/s/10153572/product_confirmation.html"
```

I have used regular expressions to extract the product code as below

```
re.findall('\d+', url)
```

However, if I try and replicate to the entire dataset ( which has multiple columns)  I get an error

```
regex = lambda x: x.re.findall('\d+')
df["new_column"] = df['url'].apply(regex)
```

> 'str' object has no attribute 're' .

Comment: In pandas, use `df['url'].str.extractall(r'\d+')` instead. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html

Comment: Use pandas str methods, df['url'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same syntax in your lambda function that you used in your scaler example:

```
regex = lambda x: re.findall('\d+', x)
```

you probably want the zeroeth element too so you don't any up with a series of lists

```
regex = lambda x: re.findall('\d+', x)[0]
```

Comment: df['url'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False)  this one does the trick